# How do I determine the IPV6 address added to VXLAN when interface is set to up?

Tags: ipv6, linux, vxlan

**Setup:**
Currently working on  a machine with Red Hat 7.2 (`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)` to be exact.)

I have a vxlan interface configured:

```
# ip link add test.123 type vxlan dev test id 123 dstport 4789
# ifconfig  test.123
test.123: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
    ether a2:3a:a8:0c:d9:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When I run:

```
# ifconfig test.132 up
# ifconfig test.123
test.123: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
    inet6 fe80::a03a:a8ff:fe0c:d976  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether a2:3a:a8:0c:d9:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 5 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Question:**
Where does the IPV6 address come from? How can I know it in advance?
I've tried setting an alternative IPv6 address before performing `up`, and I end up with two different IPV6 addresses....

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] or [unix.se] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1):

This is autoconfigured link local address. First 64 bits are always fe80:: according to [RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.6). Last 64 bits are interface ID. Interface ID is [modified MAC address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#page-20).

You can disable autoconfiguration:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/<interface>/autoconf
```

And set ipv6 address manually.

Comment: This setting will be lost after reboot. To disable this permanently you can add `IPV6INIT=no` and `IPV6_AUTOCONF=no` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-X` or your OS equivalent. You can also add to `/etc/sysconfig/network` or your OS equivalent of that file `IPV6_AUTOCONF=no` and `NETWORKING_IPV6=no` if you don't want IPv6 enabled anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [IPv6 link local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address), and this is not something specific to VXLAN. Any interface with IPv6 enabled must at least a link local address configured, and optionally other (possibly publicly routable) addresses.

Link local addresses are used only on the local network and are typically generated automatically based on the MAC address of the interface.